# What's difference between firebase vs Firebase used to get FieldValue

Tags: javascript, firebase

What I did

```
const firebase = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
const { FieldValue } = firebase.firestore;
```

**firebase** is used here

instead of

```
const firebase = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
const { FieldValue } = Firebase.firestore;
```

**Firebase** is used here

Coming from `Java world`, this is really frustrating + confusing that VS Code doesn't complain about this and it ends up giving weird bugs elsewhere.

Questions are

- How to avoid this kind of bug
- Is there any plug-in to handle this issue in VS Code
- Why VS Code didn't throw error

Comment: You are giving `firebase` name to constant. It can be any other valid identifier like `const app = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason VScode doesn't point out this error is that VScode is very bad at identifying syntax errors in JavaScript. The solution would be to use Typescript. This is one of the reasons people love Typescript, it allows you to identify bugs early.

Also, it is generally a bad practice to have two variables with the same name where the only difference is the capitalization of some characters. So you could change the name of the `firebase` variable to `app` or change the name of the `Firebase` variable to `firebaseLib`, or whatever you want.

Comment: "...change the name of the Firebase variable to firebaseLib...", do you mean in const { FieldValue } = Firebase.firestore; ?